# Why is a densely defined symmetric operator $T$ extended by its adjoint $T^*$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, unbounded-operators

This is a result I've seen stated a few times, but I can't seem to come up with a proof!

> Suppose $T$ is a densely defined linear operator with domain $D(T)\subset H$, where $H$ is a Hilbert space then if $T$ is symmetric i.e. $\langle Tx,y\rangle = \langle x,Ty\rangle$ for all $x,y \in D(T)$, it follows that the adjoint $T^*$ extends $T$, i.e. $T \subset T^*$.

What I'm having trouble showing is why $D(T)\subset D(T^*)$. Where $$D(T^*)=\{y\in H:x\mapsto \langle Tx,y\rangle \text{ is a bounded linear functional on } D(T)\}.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $y \in D(T)$, we have, due to the symmetry of $T$,

$$x \mapsto \langle Tx,y\rangle = x \mapsto \langle x, Ty\rangle,$$

and the latter is easily seen to be continuous, hence $D(T) \subset D(T^\ast)$.

Comment: After we have shown $D(T) \subset D(T^*)$ we also have to verify that $T x = T^* x$ for $x \in D(T)$, right? We know that $\langle T x, y \rangle = \langle x, T^* y \rangle$ for all $x \in D(T)$ and $y \in D(T^*)$. For $x,y \in D(T) \subset D(T^*)$ this implies $$\langle x, T^* y \rangle = \langle T x, y \rangle =\langle x, T y \rangle,$$ right?

Comment: Also, that $\Phi_y: x \mapsto \langle x, T y \rangle$ is continuous is easy to see as $\| \Phi_y(x) \| \le \| T \| \| y \| \| x \| = c \| x \|$ and it therefore is bounded?

Comment: Yes, @ViktorGlombik, that's correct, the symmetry relation shows that the adjoint _relation_ extends $T$, and then it follows that $T^{\ast}$ is a map, since $T$ is densely defined. Personally, I don't find the characterisation "$D(T^{\ast}) = \{y : x \mapsto \langle Tx, y\rangle \text{ is continuous}\}$" so very useful, I find $D(T^{\ast}) = \{ y : (\exists z)(\forall x \in D(T))(\langle Tx, y\rangle = \langle x, z\rangle)\}$ more useful. And in your argument for the continuity there's a glitch, $T$ is usually not bounded, so $\lVert T\rVert$ is undefined or $+\infty$. You need to keep the…

Comment: …$y$ together with the $T$, $$\lvert\langle x, Ty\rangle \rvert \leqslant \lVert Ty\rVert\cdot \lVert x\rVert\,.$$ Now $\lVert Ty\rVert$ is a well-defined non-negative real number, even if $T$ is unbounded.